# Python Flask Logging - Ends up in two places

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have a strange bug in my server's logging code. I am trying to have two different log files. One for errors and warnings (ERROR_LOG), and one for the log data that the server generates by calling "INFO" (STUDENT_INTERACTION_LOG). The logging behavior is a little different between development and production instances, but only insofar as the STUDENT_INTERACTION_LOG is a TimedRotatingFileHandler instead of a RotatingFileHandler. There's a third logger (FeedbackHandler) that does some debug stuff, and is largely irrelevant.

The following code is used to set-up the logging:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter':'basicFormatter'
        },
        'errorHandler': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': ERROR_LOG,
            'formatter': 'basicFormatter'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'Feedbackfull': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['FeedbackHandler']
        },
        'SystemLogger': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'handlers': ['console']
        },
        'StudentInteractions': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['fileHandler']
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console', 'errorHandler']
    },
    'formatters': {
        'basicFormatter': {
            'format': '%(name)s[%(levelname)s] - %(message)s'
        },
        'simpleFormatter': {
            'format': '%(message)s'
        }
    }
}
LOG_FILENAME = os.path.join(app.config['ROOT_DIRECTORY'], 'log/feedbackfull/feedbackfull.log')
if app.config['IS_PRODUCTION']:
    LOGGING['handlers']['fileHandler'] = {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': STUDENT_INTERACTION_LOG,
        'when': 'D',
        'formatter': 'simpleFormatter'
    }
else:
    LOGGING['handlers']['fileHandler'] = {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': STUDENT_INTERACTION_LOG,
        'formatter': 'simpleFormatter'
    }
    LOGGING
LOGGING['handlers']['FeedbackHandler'] = {
    'filename': LOG_FILENAME,
    'formatter': 'simpleFormatter',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler'
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

Later in different modules, I use something like the following:

```
student_interactions_logger = logging.getLogger('StudentInteractions')
student_interactions_logger.info("Data will go here.")
```

On reviewing my logs, I am surprised that some (but not all?) of the INFO level logs go to the Error log sometimes. I have not found a consistent reason why. Anyone have any insight? It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the problem was caused by an incorrect level for the handlers. After setting the 'level' to 'WARNING' for both the 'console' and 'errorHandler', the logging seems to be correct.